# Can't execute command from crontab?

Tags: php, command-line, cron, execute

I want to update some stuff in my database everyday at 16:00.

So I use crontab which execute command which run my file.php which run the update. It works perfectly when I execute the command in the bash but There is a problem with the crontab.

crontab:

```
00 16 * * * ./etc/cron.daily/maj_cat
```

maj_cat

```
php var/www/dev/update.php
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably missing a prefixing slash in `var/www...`

Comment: What is root's home directory? (Or maybe you should lose the . in the path name). Did you set execute bits on maj_cat? And a `#!/bin/sh` line is best practice nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

./etc/cron.daily/maj_cat is a relative path, and var/www/dev/update.php too, try:

```
00 16 * * * /etc/cron.daily/maj_cat
```

and maj_cat:

```
php /var/www/dev/update.php
```

To you can do:

```
00 16 * * * /usr/bin/env php /var/www/dev/update.php
```

Comment: Yep! It run the script but it update juste two articles in a database of 100 articles...Maybe I need to declare running time?

Comment: Yea, yo can set in the file or in the php.ini of CLI: /etc/php5/cli/php.ini (depend the Linux distro or bsd, etc), the directive is : max_execution_time, ex: max_execution_time = 3600 // one hour

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the full path to PHP,

type in:
whereis php

typically PHP resides at /usr/bin/php

resulting in:
/usr/bin/php /var/www/dev/update.php

I find it useful to test a crontab is being executed by outputting to a file, so you know that the cron is actually being executed, something like:

/usr/bin/php /var/www/dev/update.php > output.txt

You will probably be better off putting a forward slash before "var" too as I've shown above.

Answer (score 1):

probably the crondeaemon does not use the PATH variable that is set when you do it by hand.
Be sure that php is in the path (in the head of your crontab).

Otherwise you could try using absolut paths in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Cron uses a default profile when it runs cronjobs, which will likely have a different PATH variable than what you use when logged in. You can load your own profile at the beginning of the cronjob, to ensure that the cronjob's environment matches your logged in environment.

You can load your profile in this way:

```
00 16 * * * ~/.profile; ./etc/cron.daily/maj_cat
```